# Is is possible to get function's static value?

Tags: php

I never realized functions in PHP can have their own static variables, like this:

```php
function example() {
    static $heavy;

    if ($heavy === null) {
        $heavy = new HeavyClass();
    }

    return $heavy->doSomething();
}
```

My question is, is it possible to access this static value from the outside? Something like `example::$heavy`, which obviously doesn't work.

Comment: Not as far as I know. If you need to do this, why not make it a global variable instead?

Comment: It's inside a library defining a global helper. I would make it global myself :)

Comment: Looks like you can do it with the Reflection library: http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunctionabstract.getstaticvariables.php

Comment: @Barmar it does work, yay! I did `(new ReflectionFunction('example'))->getStaticVariables()['heavy']` and it worked like a charm. Can you please add it as an answer, so others can benefit from that and you get a candy?

Comment: You can post your own answer.

Comment: I know, but you won't get a candy then.

Comment: I pointed you in the right direction, you filled in the details. I've had enough candy. :)

Comment: Alrighty then, I will eat my candy while thinking about you, haha!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, this can be done via [ReflectionFunctionAbstract::getStaticVariables()](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunctionabstract.getstaticvariables.php) method.

Example:

```php
$heavy = (new ReflectionFunction('example'))->getStaticVariables()['heavy'];
```